# DevServer expecting .WAR when I upload the application of .EAR format

Tags: java, maven

This application was built 15 years ago, I guess. The client has sought an upgrade/modification of this app, which I am not aware of.

I have built some `POM.xml` scripts. When I tried to upload it in development server, it was expecting a `.WAR` file inside the `.EAR` that I had uploaded.

Here is my `pom.xml` script. Please suggest some modifications.

```
<groupId>itaras</groupId>
<artifactId>itaras</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ear</packaging>
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <type>war</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <finalName>MyEarFile</finalName>
        <version>5</version>
        <generatedDescriptorLocation>$D:/itaras/ITARAS_Branch_3Aug2017/itaras/WebContent</generatedDescriptorLocation>
        <modules>
          <webModule>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <uri>appITARAS.war</uri>
            <bundleFileName>appITARAS.war</bundleFileName>
            <contextRoot>/ITARAS</contextRoot>
          </webModule>
        </modules>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>          
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a parent pom like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>itaras</groupId>
  <artifactId>itaras</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>      
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>itaras-ear</module>
    <module>itaras-war</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

Then you will have a war project which is a child/module of the parent.  This will be your existing project like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>itaras</groupId>
    <artifactId>itaras</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>itaras-war</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
.....
```

Then you will have an ear project which will include the war project as a dependency, something like:

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>itaras</groupId>
    <artifactId>itaras</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>itaras-ear</artifactId>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>

  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>itaras</groupId>
     <artifactId>itaras-war</artifactId>
     <version>${project.version}</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Kindly answer this questionhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982360/ear-and-war-not-building