# Ear and WAR not building

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Upon executing the command 'maven clean install', I get the following console screen.
[My output console using m2eclipse plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOmj1.png)

When I visit the path mentioned in the console screen, there is only a copy of pom.xml file but not EAR and WAR file.

[folder view mentioned in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU8wP.png)

I wish to build an EAR file which contains a WAR file.
This question was posted by me today and I followed the steps as mentioned by the Gentleman.

I will also share my parent pom.xml

```
    <artifactId>itaras</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

 <name>itaras</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


   <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>


    <build>
   <plugins>
   <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
 </plugin>

   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <finalName>MyEarFile</finalName>
            <version>5</version>
             <generatedDescriptorLocation>$D:/itaras
  /ITARAS_Branch_3Aug2017/itaras/WebContent
 </generatedDescriptorLocation>
            <modules>
                    <webModule>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <uri>appITARAS.war</uri>
                    <bundleFileName>appITARAS.war</bundleFileName>
                    <contextRoot>/ITARAS</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
               </modules>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>          
   </plugins>
  </build>
   <groupId>itaras</groupId>
  <profiles>
   <profile>
 <modules>
   <module>itaras-ear</module>
    <module>itaras-war</module>
    <module>?</module>
 </modules>
 </profile>
  </profiles>

 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>itaras</groupId>
        <artifactId>itaras-war</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   </project>
```

Comment: maven package should build the war

Comment: I am  not sure where to look for the built ITARAS 1.0 snapshot.. Can u help me?

Comment: BTW, maven package command helped me solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you say `<packaging>pom</packaging>`, you only build a pom. Your child project needs to specify `war` or `ear` as packaging.